# Laravel 9 upgrade issue during deployment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel-9, php-8.1

I have an existing Laravel 8 application that is deployed in Google cloud App Engine.

I'm trying to upgrade to Laravel 9, however facing a strange issue while trying to deploy -

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 92fff745-cde1-47d0-b66f-5ec5ac4fc026 status: FAILURE
...n Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php:42
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:55
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:71
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:76
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php:27
Class App\Http\Controllers\api\AllApiController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Api/AllApiController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
54 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache
> php artisan config:clear

In Compiler.php line 66:
                                      
  Please provide a valid cache path.  
                                      

Script php artisan config:clear handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

The error occurs while trying to clear either of route, cache or config. This is the relevant section in `composer.json` that triggers the error -

```
"scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],     
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan config:clear"
            "php artisan route:clear",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
    }
```

I have tried to Google but haven't found any relevant answer yet. I am not quite sure what is causing this issue and kind of exhausted all the avenues I could think of. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I am upgrading from Laravel `8.0` to `9.11` and PHP `7.2` to `8.0.2`.

In my `app.yaml`, runtime of app engine is set to `php81`.

Some users had similar error because of `storage` directory structure. I have the following directory structure under storage, however I don't think the error is related to this. My directory structure hasn't changed at all, the only change is the upgrade of Laravel and PHP.

```
storage
 - framework
   - cache
      - data
   - sessions
   - views
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try running ```composer self-update``` and then try running ```composer global update```.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the runtime to `php80`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42231

Comment: Deprecation notice is not related to this, I think. Also, Google App Engine currently only supports `php81`

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid runtime 'php80' specified. Accepted runtimes are: [php, php55, python27, java, java7, java8, nodejs8, php72, nodejs16, php74, python310, php73, nodejs10, ruby30, nodejs14, nodejs12, java17, php81, java11, go116, go114, go115, go112, python38, go113, python37, go111, python39, ruby27, ruby26, ruby25]

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed the new PHP version did you run composer global update so that you upgrade the global composer dependencies?

You can try running composer self-update and then try running global update.

You may also refer to this [GitHub link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42199).